# Install MC with SMB support

Tags: linux, samba, smb, midnight-commander

how to install MC (Midnight Commander) with Samba support (smb:// link like ftp).
Im unable to install it thou apt-get. Ive got just mc version without smb.
And install from sources failed. I try to google it, but no success.

Im on Ubuntu 11 (actually on XBMC 11, but its like Ubuntu).
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Download the source and build dependencies:

```
mkdir ~/.mc
cd !$
apt-get source mc
sudo apt-get build-dep mc
```

Open the `mc-4.8.3/debian/rules` file and uncomment this line `--enable-vfs-smb=yes`. Don't forget to append a backslash character at the end of the above line:

```
override_dh_auto_configure:
        dh_auto_configure -- AWK="awk" \
                --libexecdir='$${prefix}/lib' \
                --with-x \
                --with-screen=slang \
                --disable-rpath \
                --disable-static \
                --enable-vfs-undelfs \
                --enable-tests \
                --enable-vfs-smb=yes
```

Build binary from source:

```
cd mc-4.8.3/
sudo dpkg-buildpackage
```

then install by running:

```
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i mc_4.8.3-9_i386.deb
```

Verify that you see the `smbfs` at the `Virtual File Systems` line:

```
$ mc -V
GNU Midnight Commander 4.8.3
Built with GLib 2.34.0
Using the S-Lang library with terminfo database
With builtin Editor
With subshell support as default
With support for background operations
With mouse support on xterm and Linux console
With support for X11 events
With internationalization support
With multiple codepages support
Virtual File Systems: cpiofs, tarfs, sfs, extfs, ext2undelfs, ftpfs, fish, smbfs
Data types: char: 8; int: 32; long: 32; void *: 32; size_t: 32; off_t: 64;
```

Source: http://prolinux.org/content/midnight-commander-i-samba.php

Comment: When editing `debian/rules`, take care to make sure the line continuation char '\' is enabled on the line above the newly uncommented line of  `--enable-vfs-smb=yes`  
If you encounter signing errors, change `sudo dpkg-buildpackage` to `sudo dpkg-buildpackage -us -us`.  Note!  There are security implications here.  Please read https://serverfault.com/questions/191785/how-can-i-properly-sign-a-package-i-modified-and-recompiled